# infinite loop in a WebHook

Tags: php, webhooks, facebook-messenger

I'm doing a facebook messenger bot. After you start it, it makes a call to WebHook. 
Unfortunately after the first start will not stop throwing the same call with the same parameters.
The settings are:

- message_deliveries;
- message_reads;
- messages;
- messaging_optins;
- messaging_postbacks.

The source code is this: https://github.com/Ellusu/nuraghebot-facebookmessenger/blob/master/index.php

Where am I wrong?
Why does only one call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your code I decided that you can't setup your webhook, so from [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/setup#webhook_setup)

> At your webhook URL, add code for verification. Your code should
>   expect the Verify Token you previously defined, and respond with the
>   challenge sent back in the verification request. Click the "Verify and
>   Save" button in the New Page Subscription to call your webhook with a
>   GET request.

So, for PHP to make a success with webhook setup you must return **hub_challenge** parameter.

Define $verify_token with your token and add something like:

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['hub_mode']) && $_REQUEST['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'] == $verify_token) {

    // Webhook setup request
    echo $_REQUEST['hub_challenge']; exit;
}
```

After success setup, you can delete this code from your script.

Or, if your webhook already hooked:

You should skip any *read* and *delivery* messages, like this:

```
if (!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'])) {
    foreach ($input['entry'][0]['messaging'] as $message) {

        // Skipping delivery messages
        if (!empty($message['delivery'])) {
            continue;
        }

        // Skipping read messages
        if (!empty($message['read'])) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you can deselect *message_reads* & *message_deliveries* checkboxes in Page Subscription section of your Facebook Page Settings/Webhooks.

Comment: that task has already been made during the creation and has already been canceled . Without this operation it was not possible to make calls.

Comment: Do you have some logs? What exactly message do you receive?

Comment: Also, I tested your code on my bot and it works correctly.

Comment: No error. I sent the message and he infinitely running the code in webhooks

Comment: Ok, I think you get some delivery or read message and this leads to infinitive loop.
You should skip this messages [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39352131/3775164)