# Facebook - Messaging webhook keeps infinitely looping the callback php file

Tags: php, facebook, bots, messenger

while my page recive any notification .. the callback file infinitely running itself without stopping
here is the code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';   
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',           
  'app_secret' => '{app_secret}',   
  'graph_api_version' => 'v5.0',
]);
$feedData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($feedData);
if ($data->object == "page") {   
  try {
    $response = $fb->post(
      '/me/messages',
      array (
        'recipient' => '{
          "id": "{id}"
        }',
        'message' => '{
          "text": "{text}"
        }'
      ),
     $accesstoken
    );
  } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }
  $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();  
  }
```

so the user will infinitely recive the same message without stopping

i tried the solution here
[infinite loop in a WebHook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377533/infinite-loop-in-a-webhook)

anyone can help me with this please to make it run just once?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
  // Returns a `FacebookFacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->get(
    '/{to_id}?fields=conversations{messages{message}}',
    $accesstoken
  );
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
$idchk = $response->getGraphNode();
$datachk = json_decode($idchk);
if (($data->object == "page")&&(strpos($idchk,'hey')=="")) {   
  try {
    $response = $fb->post(
      '/me/messages',
      array (
        'recipient' => '{
          "id": "{to_id}"
        }',
        'message' => '{
          "text": "hey"
        }'
      ),
     $accesstoken
    );

    exit;
  } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

    exit;

  } catch(FacebookExceptionsFacebookSDKException $e) {

    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

}}

    exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but i've struggled with this same problem while developing a chatbot of my own. There is a combination of 2 solutions that fixed this issue:

**Solution 1:** If there is no input, or no message text and payload, the code exits. Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if(empty($input))
    exit();

$messageText = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
$messagePayload = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['postback']['payload'];

if(empty($messageText) && empty($messagePayload)) {
    exit();
}
```

This was necessary because the chatbot just seemed to keep spamming my entry-point with empty requests over and over again. However...

**Solution 2:** I saved all message id-s in the database, and exit out if one is already being processed. This was necessary because I kept receiving certain messages 2 or 3 times in the API, and I had to avoid answering the same message twice. Here is a short excerpt:

```
$mid = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['mid'];
$received = $this->user->isReceived($mid); // To avoid reacting to the same message twice
if($received) {
    exit();
} else {
    $this->user->logMsg($mid);
}
```

In the `isReceived` function, I check if the custom table of message id-s already contains this message. In the `logMsg` function, I store the id. They are a bit more complicated and framework-dependant however, so you will have to write these functions on your own, as you see them fit for your project.

Good luck, I hope someone chimes in with a better solution.